# FAILURE Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework

how to solve this?
command  ionic cordova build android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/                                                                                                                4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Answer (score 1):

Set the JAVA_OPTS system variable (-Xmszzzm -minimum , -Xmxzzzm - maximum)
          `JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m"`
(set as per requirement)
...hope this will help you

Comment: This will work, as the problem is related to Gradle requiring 2GB of consecutive free RAM, which is a huge amount.